I need Help evaluate series :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n+2)}$
I need Help evaluate series :$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n+2)}$$
$$s(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n+2)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(x+2)...(x+n+2)} $$
We have :
$$\frac{n!}{(x+2)...(x+n+2)}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+2)...(x+n+1)}-\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+3)...(x+n+2)}$$
Therfore:
$$s(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+2)...(x+n+1)}-\frac{1}{x+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+3)...(x+n+2)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}+s(x)-\frac{x+2}{x+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n+2)}$$
This implies that :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+2)(x+3)...(x+n+2)}=\frac{1}{(x+2)^2}$$
Now put x:=x-1
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n+2)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$$
I faced this problem for more than an hour while trying to find a solution to it.  When I started asking the question and wrote the problem and all the details, I found the solution. I did not delete it so that all the time I spent writing this problem would not be in vain.   Are there other ways to solve??

Does this answer your question? Showing that $\frac 1 {(x+1)^2}=\frac 1 {(x+1)(x+2)}+\frac {1!} {(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)} + \frac {2!} {(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)} + \cdots$ (found using Approach$0$)
